# Can the human body utilize electricity?

Tags: biochemistry, cell-biology, electrophysiology

In any way could the body store electricity supplied externally?

[image]

Comment: Electron is a measure of charge, not a charge carrier, in the same way yard is a measure of distance, not a thing with the length of one yard.

Comment: @MartinKlvana The [electron](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electron) is a subatomic particle, symbol e− or β−, whose electric charge is negative one elementary charge.

Comment: electron transfer in mtDNA and nerves (although in nerves, the moving charges are ions, not electrons).

Comment: I don't understand your second sentence. It contains no verb. What exactly are you trying to ask here. I don't understand either the purpose or meaning of the picture. Can you clarify this?

Comment: @Remi.b I hope that is better.

Comment: You seem to be interested in a medical application. Is your question "Can our body sense an electrical current?", "Can our body produce an electrical current?", "Can we cure breast cancer with an electrical current?", "Do different organelles communciate through an electrical current?"etc...

Comment: @Remi.b more like if our body has a external consistent charge will our body adapt or has the ability to make use of it

Comment: @Remi.b: What is "negative" and what is "elementary" and what is "particle"? And what do you call that which has a charge different from "negative one elementary charge"? How can elementary charge become delocalized? And so on and so on. "Electron does not exist." --Kenneth Lee Wheeler (citing Nikola Tesla, among others) https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCVcxJ9k14bi__-uA1cGkEcA

Comment: @Remi.b very nice.

Comment: I would like this to be migrated to health SE. please

Comment: @MartinKlvana Well you might want to discuss this on physics.SE or philosophy.SE but all commonly accepted source of information on the subject suggest that an electron is a particle which carry a charge (which has arbitrarily decided to be negative). An obscure youtube channel with 4 videos, none of them where seen more than 8k won't be a good argument. But let's not further this discussion here, it is not the place.

Comment: @Remi.b: "electron" is an example of "reification of attributes" fallacy. What is "commonly accepted" is usually wrong. (4 videos? More like 400.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not to be a smartass, but do you not consider the mitochondrial electron transport chain to already sort of do that? When we consider that actual movement of electrons to be a step in the conversion of chemical potential in fatty acids and carbohydrates to phosphorylating ADP for later mechanical energy. Just a thought.

Although I'm assuming you mean somehow utilizing a current flow through the body from an outside source.

Answer (score 5):

No, the human body cannot utilize externally applied electricity.  Applying electricity to the body will either have no effect, if the amount is small, or will disrupt normal functions of the body or cause injury if the amount is larger.

An overview of the effects of electricity (for doctors) can be found in "[Conduction of Electrical Current to and Through the Human Body: A Review](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC2763825/)".